# Github not loading on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: git, github, ubuntu-18.04

For some reason, I am not able to load Github on my Ubuntu 18.04 machine in any way. I tried Crome and Firefox. I have tried to unset the proxy using -

```
git config --global --unset http.proxy
git config --global --unset https.proxy
```

I also tried to set it to blank

```
git config --global http.proxy ""
git config --global https.proxy ""
```

I have tried clearing cache, manually deleting and recreating the .gitconf file in the home folder. But nothing seems to work. Also git clone requests are not being executed from the command line. The site simply states that the connection has been timed out.

I finally tried wireshark to capture connection information. When I type in any url from github.com, it gives nothing. After a few minutes when I get the timed out error, I get this from the wireshark -

```
No.     Time           Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
    205 115.210340122  192.168.29.136        35.224.99.156         TCP      74     54616 → 80 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=64240 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=1144885874 TSecr=0 WS=128

Frame 205: 74 bytes on wire (592 bits), 74 bytes captured (592 bits) on interface 0
Ethernet II, Src: D-LinkIn_ac:e5:4a (78:32:1b:ac:e5:4a), Dst: 14:ae:85:e1:09:98 (14:ae:85:e1:09:98)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 192.168.29.136, Dst: 35.224.99.156
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: 54616, Dst Port: 80, Seq: 0, Len: 0

No.     Time           Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
    214 116.211223359  192.168.29.136        35.224.99.156         TCP      74     [TCP Retransmission] 54616 → 80 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=64240 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=1144886875 TSecr=0 WS=128

Frame 214: 74 bytes on wire (592 bits), 74 bytes captured (592 bits) on interface 0
Ethernet II, Src: D-LinkIn_ac:e5:4a (78:32:1b:ac:e5:4a), Dst: 14:ae:85:e1:09:98 (14:ae:85:e1:09:98)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 192.168.29.136, Dst: 35.224.99.156
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: 54616, Dst Port: 80, Seq: 0, Len: 0

No.     Time           Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
    215 118.227149032  192.168.29.136        35.224.99.156         TCP      74     [TCP Retransmission] 54616 → 80 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=64240 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=1144888891 TSecr=0 WS=128

Frame 215: 74 bytes on wire (592 bits), 74 bytes captured (592 bits) on interface 0
Ethernet II, Src: D-LinkIn_ac:e5:4a (78:32:1b:ac:e5:4a), Dst: 14:ae:85:e1:09:98 (14:ae:85:e1:09:98)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 192.168.29.136, Dst: 35.224.99.156
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: 54616, Dst Port: 80, Seq: 0, Len: 0

No.     Time           Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
    220 122.387150649  192.168.29.136        35.224.99.156         TCP      74     [TCP Retransmission] 54616 → 80 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=64240 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=1144893051 TSecr=0 WS=128

Frame 220: 74 bytes on wire (592 bits), 74 bytes captured (592 bits) on interface 0
Ethernet II, Src: D-LinkIn_ac:e5:4a (78:32:1b:ac:e5:4a), Dst: 14:ae:85:e1:09:98 (14:ae:85:e1:09:98)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 192.168.29.136, Dst: 35.224.99.156
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: 54616, Dst Port: 80, Seq: 0, Len: 0

No.     Time           Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
    227 130.706783205  192.168.29.136        35.224.99.156         TCP      74     [TCP Retransmission] 54616 → 80 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=64240 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=1144901243 TSecr=0 WS=128

Frame 227: 74 bytes on wire (592 bits), 74 bytes captured (592 bits) on interface 0
Ethernet II, Src: D-LinkIn_ac:e5:4a (78:32:1b:ac:e5:4a), Dst: 14:ae:85:e1:09:98 (14:ae:85:e1:09:98)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 192.168.29.136, Dst: 35.224.99.156
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: 54616, Dst Port: 80, Seq: 0, Len: 0
```

Please help.

Comment: So it appears that any/all connection attempts to github.com hang for awhile, then ultimately fail with a "timeout", correct?  Q: Have you tried connecting from a different LAN?  It sounds like your LAN's firewall, for whatever reason, is blocking github.com.  SUGGESTION: have you tried both HTTPS ... and SSH?

Comment: @paulsm4 I tried with a different device in the same internet connection. It works. I think this is something device specific. I tried http, https. Not sure how to try with ssh.

Comment: `35.224.99.156` is a valid address ... for a Google Cloud host!  Not github.com.  "ping github.com" => `192.30.255.113` on my host.  Your Ubuntu's DNS is broken. 
 SUGGESTIONS: 1) do a "ping github.com" from one of your hosts that successfully connect to GitHub and compare the IP addresses. 2) Fix DNS on your broken server.  3) Try changing the DNS servers on your (broken!) Ubuntu to the same as your working host.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Not sure how to try with ssh.

Simply try

```
ssh -Tv git@github.com
git ls-remote git@github.com:<me>/<myRepo>
```

If it does not work, that could mean you are not able to contact github.com.

Check your environment variables for anything related to proxy

```
env|grep -i proxy
```

Comment: The line `env|grep -i proxy` does not return anything

The line - `ssh -Tv git@github` returns -
```
OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3, OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
ssh: Could not resolve hostname github: Name or service not known
```
The line git ls remore returns -
ssh: connect to host github.com port 22: Connection timed out

Comment: @RuddradevRoychoudhury Sorry, I meant `ssh -Tv git@github.com`

Comment: The connection is still getting timed out- `debug1: connect to address 192.30.253.112 port 22: Connection timed out
`

Comment: @RuddradevRoychoudhury github.com IP is 140.82.121.4, so it is likely you have a network/DNS issue of some kind. Can you ping github.com?

Comment: Ping also gets timed out. But it works on my other Ubuntu machines on the same network. Can I check where the network issue is arising from?

Comment: @RuddradevRoychoudhury Not sure. Maybe a firewall issue? Can you mention the network problem on your local IT support to understand why this specific server does not have internet access?

Comment: @VonC: 35.224.99.156 is a valid external IP address, which is why I originally thought "firewall".  But in retrospect, it's the *WRONG* address.  So your first guess is the likeliest - the OPs DNS is broken.  Perhaps all he needs to do is change the name servers?